# how to solve async problem in javascript ( MVC pattern. )

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, model-view-controller, async-await

there is a problem with asynchronous processing, but I don't know how to solve it.

I was working on the MVC pattern.

The controller should receive the model and hand over the data to the view, but the data received from the model is displayed as undefined.

here is code.

`controller`

[image]

`model`

[image]

when console.log(model)

[image]

If it is OK, the data should be in the list.(in `this.#list`)

but But as you can see, it is Array(0)

I don't know how to solve it. I spent 2 to 3 hours. please help!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Wait for the model to have data before you render the view... (something like `model.loadData().then(() => view.render(model))`)

Comment: Don't try to put asynchronous code in a constructor. Ask yourself do you even have an instance of a controller before that data is loaded? If not, write a static asynchronous function that loads the data and returns an instance of controller after constructing it for you. Otherwise require the user to call loadData on the constructed instance of controller.

Comment: `async` functions synchronously return a pending promise before `await` operations within the function body have completed. Hence the constructor returns before data has loaded.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)